# Knockoutjs:Select data binding behaviour

Tags: knockout.js

From the dropdown of countries if United States is selected as country it should display the state as a dropdown else it should be a simple input text box.

We have below Country select dropdown which takes an array as options:

```
<select class="form-control" name="sCountry" aria-required="true"
        data-bind="enable: $parents[1].shippingCountriesPriceListGroup().length, options: $parents[1].shippingCountriesPriceListGroup, optionsText: 'displayName',
                             optionsValue: 'countryCode', optionsCaption: $parents[1].resources().countryText, value: selectedCountry,
</select>
```

I have used knockout `if` and `ifnot` bindings to achieve the above condition of displaying state dropdown if selected country is United States.

knockout data binding:

```
<!-- ko if:selectedCountry()=="US" -->
   <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <label class="control-label"
                       data-bind="widgetLocaleText:'stateText', attr: {for: $addrPrefix + 'CC-checkoutAddressBook-sstate'}"></label>
<select class="col-md-12 form-control" name="sState" id="CC-checkoutAddressBook-sstate" aria-required="true"
                    data-bind="options: $parents[1].US_stateList, optionsText: 'displayName', optionsValue: 'abbreviation',optionsCaption:'Choose State..',
                    value: tms_state,attr: {id: $addrPrefix + 'CC-checkoutAddressBook-sstate'}">
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot:selectedCountry()=="US" -->
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <label class="control-label"
                       data-bind="widgetLocaleText:'stateText', attr: {for: $addrPrefix + 'CC-checkoutAddressBook-sstate'}"></label>
                <input class="col-md-12 form-control" name="sState"
                       aria-required="true"
                       data-bind="value: tms_state, attr: {id: $addrPrefix + 'CC-checkoutAddressBook-sstate'}">
            </div>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Javascript code:

US_stateList Array:

```
US_stateList:ko.observableArray([{displayName:"Armed Forces Americas",abbreviation:"AA"},{displayName:"Armed Forces Europe",abbreviation:"AE"},{displayName:"Alabama",abbreviation:"AL"},{displayName:"Alaska",abbreviation:"AK"}])
```

I have subscribed the `selectedCountry` observable value to set the state box value as null or empty when a NON US state is getting selected.

```
widget.newShippingAddress().selectedCountry.subscribe(function(newValue){
                    if ((widget.newShippingAddress().tms_state() !== undefined) ||
                    (widget.newShippingAddress().tms_state() !== '')) {
                    // needs to be null rather than empty string
                    // or knockout resets to dropdown value

                        widget.newShippingAddress().tms_state(null);
                }
                });
```

The expected outcome is to show the state field as dropdown if the selected country is US else state field should be displayed as an empty input text box.

Actual results:

Whenever United States is selected as country,it works as expected i.e displays state select dropdown and on selecting NON US countries displays state field as empty. But, after page reload and performing the same steps again:
1)United States is selected as country, state dropdown is getting displayed.
2)Select a NON US country the state field gets populated with the pre-selected state value of United States instead of showing it as empty/null.

Comment: that's because you kinda using `tms_state` as `value` binding for both.you can add conditional check in .subscribe to make tms_state empty when you select other than US.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I got it here but you seem to be overly complicating things, is this what you are after?

```js
console.clear();
function myViewModel() {
 var self = this;
  self.countries = ko.observableArray([{name:'US', abb: 'US'}, {name: 'Canada', abb: 'CA'}]);  
  self.states = ko.observableArray([{name:'Alabama',abb:'AL'},{name:'Alaska',abb:'AK'}]);
  self.selectedCountry = ko.observable();
  self.selectedState = ko.observable();
  
  self.selectedCountry.subscribe(function () {
   self.selectedState('');
  });
  
  self.insertDataUs = function () {
   var country = { name: 'US', abb: 'US', state: { name: 'Alaska', abb: 'AK' }};
    self.selectedCountry(country.abb);
    self.selectedState(country.state.abb);
  };
  
  self.insertDataOther = function () {
  var country = { name: 'Canada', abb: 'CA', state: { name: 'Randomstate', abb: 'RS' }};
   self.selectedCountry(country.abb);
    self.selectedState(country.state.abb);
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: countries, value: selectedCountry, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'abb', optionsCaption: 'choose'"></select>
<!-- ko if: selectedCountry() != null && selectedCountry() == 'US' -->
<select data-bind="options: states, value: selectedState, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'abb', optionsCaption: 'choose'"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: selectedCountry() != null && selectedCountry() != 'US' -->
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: selectedState" />
<!-- /ko -->
<br />
<!-- ko with: selectedCountry -->
country: <span data-bind="text: _.find($root.countries(), (items) => { return items.abb == $data }).name"></span><br />
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko with: selectedState -->
state: <span data-bind="text: $root.selectedCountry() == 'US' ? _.find($root.states(), (items) => { return items.abb == $data }).name : $data"></span><br />
<!-- /ko -->
<button data-bind="click: insertDataUs">us data</button> <button data-bind="click: insertDataOther">other data</button>
```